# Instantiate calendar object outside of for loop the code does not work

Tags: java

Unable To Update Time In Every Second

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.*;
public class AppletClock extends Applet{

    Calendar calendar; 
    Thread changeTime = null;
    Thread changeBgColor = null;
    String currentTime;
    Color randomColor;
    Font font = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD+Font.ITALIC,80);

    public void init(){     
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);     

        changeTime = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            public void run(){              
                for(;;){                    
                    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();/*When I Instantiate calendar object outside of for loop this code doesnot work and the time didnt gets updated every second Its because of this factory method or something else*/
                    currentTime = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) +":"+calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

                    try{

                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                    }
                    catch(Exception e){                     
                        System.out.println(e);                      
                    }
                    repaint();                  
                }               
            }
        });
        changeTime.start();

        changeBgColor = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            public void run(){              
                for(;;){                    
                    Random random = new Random();
                    int red = random.nextInt(255);
                    int green = random.nextInt(255);
                    int blue = random.nextInt(255);
                    randomColor = new Color(red,green,blue);

                    try{

                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                    }
                    catch(Exception e){                     
                        System.out.println(e);                      
                    }
                    repaint();                  
                }               
            }
        });
        changeBgColor.start();      
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){      
        setBackground(randomColor);

        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString(currentTime,80,120);       
    }
}
/*      
        <APPLET CODE = "AppletClock.class" WIDTH = 500 HEIGHT = 200></APPLET>       
        */
```

When I Instantiate `calendar` object outside of `for` loop this code does not work and the time didn't gets updated every second. 
Its because of this factory method or something else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When calendar instance gets created it sets the time with current time so if you create instance in 2013 and access the same instance without updating it in 2014 it will still hold the time at which it was created

if you want to update instance each time you can just set the current millisecond

```
calendar.setTime(System.currentTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: No. What we're all saying is that if you instantiate it outside of the loop, you instantiate it only once, and so you only get one calendar object, containing the instantiation time.

Comment: no factory method will return you new instance each time, instance represents the state of time, so if you don't update its state it will be the same

Answer (score 3):

A Calendar represents some fixed time. So if you instantiate it once, outside of the loop, it will always represents the same time, unless you update it in the loop, using, for example

```
calendar.setTime(new Date());
```

or

```
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

That said, given that you only need the calendar inside this loop, I don't see why you wouldn't keep this solution, and declare it as a local variable instead of declaring it as a field.

Answer (score 2):

The time is set when you call  `calendar = Calendar.getInstance();` When you do that outside the loop than it is set only once and never changed any more.

Also you should consider using a ScheduledExecutorService instead of two threads. It is easier to handle and you only need one Thread.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with where you instantiate it. It's like Date, it holds the static time of the moment you instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are bothering...

You could, instead just supply a custom `DateFormat`

```
public static final DateFormat TIME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("h:M:s");
private Date currentTime;
```

Then in your thread...

```
public void run(){
    for(;;){
        currentTime = new Date();
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

And then in you paint method...

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    setBackground(randomColor);
    g.setFont(font);
    g.drawString(TIME_FORMAT.format(currentTime),80,120);
}
```

But that's just me...